# PHP REST Service Throwing Exceptions -- Wanting to Avoid Console Errors

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, console

We have a PHP service where we throw a custom Exception object (simply has a message property) . These are caught in PHP and then we do the following:

```
header($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'] . ' 400 Bad Request', true, 400);
```

This causes two things:

1) A console error if their console is up

2) The error() callback and .fail() on a deferred object to be invoked.

We want 2 without the side-effect of 1. If we set the error code to 200, only success() and then() is invoked.

Is there any middle ground we can use?

Comment: are you using jQuery for this?

Comment: Yes. Wer'e using a cominbation of jQuery ajax(), Deferreds() and Backbone.sync

Comment: Just updated my answer :) Independent of JS libraries :)

Answer (score 0):

Correction, my first answer was bullcrap.

```
if(!window.console) console = {log: function() {}};
```

This is the way to go. Use this before the `$.ajax` call (or however you do the ajax request).

Comment: Was hoping for possibly a different method but this will do the trick as always. ^_^ Thanks! :D

Comment: As far as i know, there's none. You could just try to write a wrapper which always returns HTTP: 200 and adds some JSON fields for error handling. Don't hesistate to mark my answer ;)